# Delphi: How can I know which of the indexed property has the string index using RTTI

Tags: delphi, rtti

Based on some code like the following:

```
TListWrapper = class
  strict private
    FList: TStringList;
    function GetItem(index: Integer): TObject; overload;
    function GetItem(index: string): TObject; overload;
  public
    property Items[index: Integer]: TObject read GetItem; default;
    property Items[index: string]: TObject read GetItem; default;
end;
```

I want to write a piece of code which get the value of the string indexed property using RTTI. Something like this:

```
var
  MyList: TListWrapper;
  InstanceType: TRttiInstanceType;
  IndexedProperty: TRttiIndexedProperty;

begin
  MyList:=TListWrapper.Create;

  LContext:=TRttiContext.Create;
  InstanceType:=LContext.GetType(MyList.ClassType) as TRttiInstanceType;
  for IndexedProperty in InstanceType.GetIndexedProperties do
    if IndexedProperty.Name.ToLower = 'items' then
    begin
      //There are two indexed properties with name 'items'
    end;
  LContext.Free;
  MyList.Free;
end;
```

**Question:** How can I know which of the indexed property has the string index so that I can then get the value like this?

```
IndexedProperty.GetValue(MyList, ['some_string_index']);
```

Note: I am using Delphi 10.2.3 (Tokyo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the read method parameters. Something like this:

```
readingMethod := IndexedProperty.ReadMethod;
readMethodParameters := readingMethod.GetParameters;
if readMethodParameters[0].ParamType.TypeKind = tkUString then
  // We have the string version
```

You should obviously check that the readMethod is assigned and that the number of parameters is greater than zero, etc.

*From Remy:*

In this case, the string type is tkUString (UnicodeString) and it has been this way since Delphi 2009.

Comment: The standard `string` type in D2009+ is `UnicodeString`, so the `TypeKind` will be `tkUString` in this example (`tkString` is `ShortString`, `tkLString` is `AnsiString`, and `tkWString` is `WideString`).